# High precision queue statistics from RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

I need to log with the highest possible precision the rate with which messages enter and leave a particular queue in Rabbit. I know the API already provides publishing and delivering rates, but I am interested in **capturing** raw incoming and outgoing values in a **known** period of time, so that I can **estimate** rates with higher precision and time periods of my choice.

Ideally, I would check on-demand (i.e. on a schedule of my choice) e.g. the current cumulative count of messages that have entered the queue so far ("published" messages), and the current cumulative count of messages consumed ("delivered" messages).

With these types of cumulative counts, I could:

- Compute my own **deltas** of messages entering or exiting the queue, e.g. doing `Δ_count = cumulative_count(t) - cumulative_count(t-1)`
- Compute **throughput** **rates**  doing `throughput = Δ_count / Δ_time`
- Potentially infer **how long** messages stay on the queue throughout the day.

The last two would ideally rely on the precise timestamps when those cumulative counts were calculated.

---

I am trying to solve this problem directly using [RabbitMQ’s API](https://rawcdn.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/rabbitmq_v3_6_14/priv/www/doc/stats.html), but I’m encountering a problem when doing so. When I calculate the message cumulative count in the queue, I get a number that I don’t expect.

For example consider the screenshot below.

[image]

The `Δ_message_count` between entries 90 and 91 is `1810-1633 = 177`. So, as I stated, I suppose that the difference between published and delivered messages should be `177` as well (in particular, 177 more messages published than delivered).

However, when I calculate these differences, I see that the difference is not `177`:

- Δ of published (incoming) messages: `13417517652009 - 13417517651765 = 244`
- Δ of delivered (outgoing) messages: `1341751765667 - 1341751765450 = 217`

so we get `244 - 217 =`**`27`** messages. This suggests that there are `177 - 27 = 150` messages **"unaccounted" for**.

Why?

I tried taking into account the redelivered messages given by the API but they were constant when I run my tests, suggesting that there were no redelivered messages, so I wouldn't expect that to play a role.